# How many messages can a single AWS Lambda function process at once?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have project with the following workflow:

1. Pull files from server and upload to S3
2. When files hit S3, a message is sent to a topic using SNS
3. The lambda function subscribed to said topic will then process files by doing calculations

So far, I have not experienced any issues, but I wonder if this is a use case for `SQS`?

How many messages can my Lambda function handle all at once? If I am pulling hundreds of files, is `SQS` a necessity?

Comment: How many SQS or SNS messages? What have you found online already?

Comment: I need the lambda function to be able to handle maybe 1000 or more messages at times. And it looks like SQS is what is recommended, but I am not seeing anything online that says SNS and Lambda will fail if I have thousands of messages.

Comment: We can't tell you how many messages your Lambda can process because we have no idea what your Lambda function actually does. You can measure it, and estimate accordingly.

Comment: Well does that matter? Each message will trigger a "new" instance of the Lambda function right? Each message is processed individually as far as I can tell. It can already process hundreds of messages, but I am wondering about thousands

Comment: Your question was about "a single AWS Lambda function". If you're talking about multiple, concurrent Lambda function invocations, each handling one message, then you can read about [concurrency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/scaling-concurrency.html) here. If you use SQS, your Lambda function can be configured to process a batch of multiple messages (from SQS) in a single invocation.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are sending the invocation via Amazon SNS (eg are you also notifying other processes)? Is there a reason you do not wish to trigger the AWS Lambda function directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, parallel invocation limit is set for 1000.

You can change that limitation, but i never hit that number so far.

As soon as a lambda is done with consuming current request, it will be used for another, so if you upload 1000 files, you probably will only need about 100 lambdas, unless you need Minutes for one lambda to run.

The AWS handles the queued triggers, so even if you upload 100.000 files, they will be consumed asap, depending on diverse criteria.

You can test it with creating many little files and upload them all at once :)

For higher speed, upload them to different bucket, and simply move from bucket to bucket (speed is higher this way)

gl !